# Resizing Woocommerce cart thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My cart thumbnails in woocommerce appear cropped.

my site: http://www.laxstreetwear.com

I know how to change the thumbnail size in general with woocommerce > Settings > Products > Display but it seems like my theme is overriding these settings.

See below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS2UL.jpg

my question is: how do I change the size of "shop_isle_cart_item_image_size  (58x72 cropped)"?

Answer (score 0):

Look for a file called `wp-content/themes/shop-isle/inc/functions/setup.php` on line 126. The theme creator has hard-coded it in there. However instead of modifying a theme that could get updated and possibly undo your changes, edit the **functions.php** file in your child theme and add the following code:

```
function func321_replace_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'shop_isle_cart_item_image_size', 58, 72, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'func321_replace_image_sizes' );
```

This should allow you to override the size set in the base theme.

Edit: Also remember to regenerate your thumbnails once you make this change.

Comment: Thank you. It worked great with updating the setup.php file but can't make it work with functions.php in the child theme.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another method to resize image size of your product thumbnails inside of woocommerce shopping cart using CSS.

CSS code goes under (appearance > customise > additional css) of your wordpress admin dashboard. Tested and Works.

```
.woocommerce .cart.shop_table .product-thumbnail img {

   max-width: 200px; // <== Define your Shopping Cart Thumbnail Image Size

}
```

Do ensure that your source image thumbnail you have uploaded is larger than the max-width you want to apply, to avoid any image quality degradation when applying this css.